A counterexample to the extendibility property for submanifolds
Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold. We say that a bounded embedded submanifold $S\subset M$ of class $C^k$ has the extendibility property if there exists a larger embedded submanifold $\tilde{S}\subset M$ of class $C^k$, of the same dimension, such that $S\subseteq\tilde{S}$ and
\begin{equation}\label{eq:separation}
\mathsf{d}_g\left(\mathrm{cl}(S),\mathrm{cl}(\tilde{S})\setminus \tilde{S}\right) >0,
\end{equation}
where $\mathsf{d}_g$ denotes the distance induced by $g$ and $\mathrm{cl}(S)$ is the closure of $S$, i.e. the union of $S$ and its boundary points. Examples of submanifolds that have this extendibility property are:
$\bullet$ any closed manifold (i.e., compact without boundary) embedded in $M$;
$\bullet$ any embedded submanifold $S\subset M$ such that $\mathrm{cl}(S)\subset M$ is an embedded $C^k$ submanifold with boundary.
Are there examples of submanifolds that do not satisfy the extendibility property? I am not able to produce an example, not even when $M=\mathbb R^n$.

The symbol $\infty$ without the central point ?

I don't see how to answer your question.  What is $d_g$?

With this definition every submanifold is extendable as long as it is not dense in $M$. You probably forgot connectivity assumptions.

@MoisheKohan: note that $\tilde{S}$ is required to have the same dimensioni of $S$

@Raziel: Yes, of course.

If $S$ is not dense in $M$ (note that $S$ can be dense if it has the same dimension as $M$), take a closed ball $B\subset M\setminus cl(S)$, a smooth embedded disk $D\subset int(B)$ of the same dimension as $S$, and set $\tilde S:= S\cup D$.

I assumed that $d_g(X,Y)$ denotes the infimum over $d_g(x,y)$ with $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$. In that case, no matter how you choose $\tilde{S}$ (even with additional connected components) in my example,the removed central point has to be in both sets, and hence the upper distance is zero.
